# Can docker containers be connected to SRIOV virtual functions?

Tags: docker

It would be awesome to make use of existing SR-IOV capable NICs. I would like to understand if a docker containers can be attached to Virtual Functions such that they communicate over the NICs hardware bridge (instead of the virtual docker0 bridge).

To be more specific, consider this scenario:
    Container A is attached to VF#1
    Container B is attached to VF#2

A and B are linked together and when they exchange data it should happen over the hardware bridge on NIC (instead of docker0).

Is the above supported natively in docker?

If not, can pipework help here? (I have heard pipework can do amazing things)

Examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured that a little modification in pipework script can let us attach VFs to containers. Containers set up this way were able to ping each other without having to create macvlan subinterface or software bridges. This indicates that the hardware bridge in adapter is doing the L2 switching for them.

The change in pipework is basically something like this:

```
[ "$IFTYPE" = phys ] && {
  [ "$VLAN" ] && {
    [ ! -d "/sys/class/net/${IFNAME}.${VLAN}" ] && {
      ip link add link "$IFNAME" name "$IFNAME.$VLAN" mtu "$MTU" type vlan id "$VLAN"
    }
    ip link set "$IFNAME" up
    IFNAME=$IFNAME.$VLAN
  }
  # Let's not create the macvlan subinterface
  # GUEST_IFNAME=ph$NSPID$CONTAINER_IFNAME
  # ip link add link "$IFNAME" dev "$GUEST_IFNAME" mtu "$MTU" type macvlan mode bridge
  GUEST_IFNAME=$IFNAME
  ip link set "$IFNAME" up
}

ip link set "$GUEST_IFNAME" netns "$NSPID"
ip netns exec "$NSPID" ip link set "$GUEST_IFNAME" name "$CONTAINER_IFNAME"
---
```

Off-course a neater way would be to add a new argument ("--direct-attach" or something) to the script to treat specified interface differently